# Why does getAccessToken() return a shorter string than a manual call to https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

I'm doing the following whilst testing out the PHP-SDK:

```
if($_REQUEST['state'] == $_SESSION['state']) {
$token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
    . "client_id=" . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
    . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret . "&code=" . $code;
$aContext = array( 'http' => array(
                'proxy' => 'tcp://192.168.55.40:80',
                'request_fulluri' => true,
                ),
            );
$cxContext = stream_context_create($aContext);
$response = file_get_contents($token_url, FALSE, $cxContext);

$params = null;
parse_str($response, $params);

//$graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" . $params['access_token'];

//$user = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url, FALSE, $cxContext));
//var_dump($facebook->getAccessToken());
$facebook->setAccessToken($params['access_token']);
$user = $facebook->api('/me');



var_dump($user);exit;
```

$facebook->getAccessToken() returns a string of 48 chars. and params['access_token'] is 112 chars. Why is this? What do I need to do to get a valid access token using the SDK?

Answer (score 0):

Its an app access token, not a user access token.

Try using SDK's getAccessToken instead.